# Default value of Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So, here is the Html helper I've used :

```
        @Html.DropDownList("FK_gestCompte", User.Identity.Name)
```

this gives this html result :

```
 <select id="FK_gestCompte" name="FK_gestCompte"><option value="">user3</option>
 <option value="1">user1</option>
 <option value="2">admin</option>
 <option value="3">user2</option>
 <option value="5">user3</option>
 </select>
```

I don't get how I can set the first line like this :

```
 <select id="FK_gestCompte" name="FK_gestCompte"><option value="5">user3</option>
```

The selectlist I've made has been created like that inside the controller :

```
        ViewBag.FK_gestCompte = New SelectList(db.my_aspnet_users, "id", "Name")
```

any idea?

---

Here is the solution given byParv Sharma :

controller :

```
        Dim ident As Integer = (From a In db.my_aspnet_users
                             Where a.name = User.Identity.Name
                             Select a.id).FirstOrDefault()
        ViewBag.FK_gestCompte = New SelectList(db.my_aspnet_users, "id", "Name", ident)
```

view :

```
        @Html.DropDownList("FK_gestCompte")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

going by the signature of the method you are using

```
  @Html.DropDownList("FK_gestCompte", User.Identity.Name)
```

im assuing that `User.Identity.Name` is an ienumerable of `SelectListItem`
 so when you are filling this collection you can set any item as selected item using the `Selected` property of that item.

Comment: going by your ques what i cud see is that you wanted to set the last option with value 5 as default selected

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not a native english speaker, that's why I haven't been good enough to explain my issue. So, inside the controller, I've found the "select" property you wanted me to use (I think), but it doesn't change anything. I've used this inside the controller :       ViewBag.FK_gestCompte = New SelectList(db.my_aspnet_users, "id", "Name", User.Identity.Name) , using the html helper like that :      @Html.DropDownList("FK_gestCompte"). But, this doesn't select by default the guy that's currently logged in.

Comment: I found out how to do this, I needed to set the id of the guy as selected value. I edit my question with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
 its possible in this way

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserType,
                       new SelectList(new List<Tuple<string, string>>
                       {
                         new Tuple<string, string>("1", "User"),                    
                          new Tuple<string, string>("2", "Admin"),                    
                        }, "Item1", "Item2", "2"))

  Admin will be selected by default as we have set "2" as a selected value
```

Comment: I don't get how this can select by default the guy that's currently logged in

Comment: Get the id of that user in controller and pass it to view in view bag or viewmodel property. and write that viewbag / property in selected value string

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a sort.

so,`db.my_aspnet_users.OrderByDescending(i => i.id)`

edit: Just seen that the first option is `<option value="">user3</option>`

Does "user3" appear in your data source twice?

**edit 2:**

Try this:

```
var users = db.my_aspnet_users.ToList();

var userSelectList = users.OrderBy(i => i.name)
                      .Select(thisUser =>
                          new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Selected = (thisUser.name == User.Identity.Name),
                              Text = thisUser.name,
                              Value = thisUser.id.ToString()
                          });
```

Then replace the helper with

```
@Html.DropDownList("userSelectList ")
```

Comment: user3 was the guy that was currently logged. This was not given by the db,  but by User.Identity.Name

Comment: Are you trying to always make user3 always selected, or make the item selected as the person currently logged in?

Comment: make the item selected as the person currently logged in